# PHP not inserting images into directory

Tags: php, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've got a PHP script that receives data from users. The script is hosted on an AWS EC2 instance running Apache, PHP and PostGreSQL.

Here's the script:

```
$chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
$length = 5;
$fileName = '';
for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
  $fileName .= $chars[mt_rand(0, 36)];
}

$filePath = "uploads/$fileName.jpg";

$encoded_photo = $_POST['snap'];
echo $encoded_photo;
$photo = base64_decode($encoded_photo);
$file = fopen($filePath, 'wb');
fwrite($file, $photo);
fclose($file);
```

So a random filename is generated for the photo and then the `$filePath` variable is inserted into the PostGreSQL.

However when I check the `uploads/` directory it's empty. No JPEGs to be found. I believe my code to be correct, perhaps the permissions of the directory aren't correct? Could any provide any guidance?

Please note I have `host=localhost port=5432 dbname=*** user=**** password=****` in my `pg_connect()` method.

Comment: Do you have write permissions in the 'uploads' folder? 0777

Comment: @pc-shooter The permissions listed are `drwxr-x---` but I'm not sure that's the correct permission to have on a directory.

Comment: @JakeGould the `$_POST['snap']` variable is a photo sent from an android application using the `httppost` method

Comment: JakeGould is probably on the right way...Can you show whats inside the `$_POST['snap']`?

Comment: @JakeGould Sorry I meant 0755

Comment: @JakeGould I'm affraid, I've to read more about that subject, thx for pointing at!

Comment: @JakeGould the owner is the standard `ec2-user`.

Comment: @JakeGould My directory has `ec2-user ec2-user` next to the permissions when I run `ls -ld uploads/` is that not the correct set up?

Comment: @JakeGould the entire web directory is `ec2-user` from what I can see.

Comment: @JakeGould I just ran the `whoami` method and it produced `apache`. Is that the user trying to make a write but can't as it isn't the same as `ec2-user`.

Comment: @JakeGould should the PHP file script that contains the above code be owned by `apache` or `ec2-user` as well?

Answer (score -3):

Apache needs to be able to write to the uploads/ directory. One way to do this is to put the Apache user into the group on uploads/ and make sure the group has write permission on the directory.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283068/how-to-add-an-existing-user-into-a-group-in-linux

This will give the group write permission: chmod g+w uploads/

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post why/how to do this; as it stands it might not help enough.

Comment: Could you elaborate mms?